# ZXing IntentIntegrator always asks to install Barcode Scanner app

Tags: android, zxing

I am trying to use the ZXing Intent Integrator and Library to scan barcodes into my app.
When I click the scan button, it will always prompt to install the Barcode Scanner app. Even when I already have it installed.
Per the docmentation I call the scanner using

```
IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
intentIntegrator.initiateScan();
```

And then in

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanResult != null) {
            String barcode = scanResult.getContents();
            EditText txt = findViewById(focused);
            txt.setText(barcode);
            EditText next = findViewById(focused + 1);
            next.requestFocus();
        }
}
```

However, the onActivityResult never gets called.
Also in the IntentIntegrator class I found in the initiateScan method, it uses:

```
 String targetAppPackage = this.findTargetAppPackage(intentScan);
        if (targetAppPackage == null) {
            return this.showDownloadDialog();
        } else {
            intentScan.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
            intentScan.addFlags(67108864);
            intentScan.addFlags(524288);
            this.attachMoreExtras(intentScan);
            this.startActivityForResult(intentScan, 49374);
            return null;
        }
```

If I am reading this right, if the `targetAppPackage` is null, it prompts for the download. Well `targetAppPackage` is always returning null.

Any ideas? I've included the dependencies as required, but still nothing has worked.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? If the answer is Android 11+, you may need to add a `<queries>` element to your manifest for [package visibility compliance](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility).

Comment: @CommonsWare I think I figured it out. Ended up using https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded and it works great, without the need to install anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research I found [here](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) to add:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3' // Older versions may give compile errors
}
```

To the `build.gradle` file and `<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ... >` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` and it works great.
No additional applications need to be installed, and no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your android manifest

```
 <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android" />
 </queries>
```

This is part of Android's 11 new [Package Visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring) filtering feature.